# MissingComponentException there is no rigidbody2D attached to gameObject but a script is trying to access it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

Im getting this error. I have no idea why.

Heres a screen shot:

http://www.siz.co.il/my.php?i=gmfmczmo3gzl.png

And my script code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerMovementV2 : MonoBehaviour
{
public KeyCode moveUp;
public KeyCode moveDown;
public KeyCode moveRight;
public KeyCode moveLeft;

public float playerVelocity = 1;

public Rigidbody2D rigid2D;
public Vector2 vector2;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    rigid2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    vector2 = new Vector2(rigid2D.velocity.x, playerVelocity);
}


// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(moveUp))
    {
        rigid2D.velocity = vector2;
    }
    else
        if (Input.GetKey(moveDown))
        {
            rigid2D.velocity = new Vector2(rigid2D.velocity.x,playerVelocity);
        }
}
}
```

Any suggestions?

As far as i seen from the picture there is a script attached to the gmae object so what does Unity3D wants from me?

PS:
Its the latest Unity3D version. Downloaded it yesterday.

Comment: Is the script on any other object in your scene?

Answer (score 0):

After I closed the unity 3D and reoppend it the problem was solved.

Thank you  Evil Tak.